# Determine concurrent users for a mobile app performance testing

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, stress-testing

I am designing a mobile app which is assumed to have 10000 users registered. Inorder to plan for a performance testing on the application. How can i determine what percent of users from this 10000 will be concurrent users ?

is there any formula to calculate this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any existing formula and doubt that it exists as it depends on too many factors to consider:

1. Is 10 000 a maximum or it can be more
2. Will all of them be coming from different geographic locations or they are residing in the same time zone
3. Are they expected during business hours only or your application is intended to be used 24x7x365
4. How actively user is using the application and how many server side events it generates
5. Wha is the business flow of the application usage, i.e. does user do something for a short period of time and exits or does he continue using application for a longer period of time

So

- First of all I would recommend getting familiarized with the [Performance Testing Guidance for Web Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb924375.aspx) to learn more about the concept of performance testing and associated activities.
- Once you figure out how many users you will have during i.e. 1 hour time frame you can start building your JMeter Test Plan to cover all types of user activities. The easiest way would be just recording calls your application makes to the backend server(s) using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), check out [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy) guide for more details.
- When your test is ready you can run it with the anticipated number of users and see if performance is acceptable. This activity is called [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing). Depending on results this might be a final step in your testing (if you're happy with results and there are no errors)
- You might also want to check your application boundaries, i.e. how many users it can handle until errors start occurring or response time starts exceeding acceptable thresholds. This is known as [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing)